# A proof of the principle of mathematical induction

Tags: logic, induction

Is there a definition of the natural number in which someone might be able to prove "The Principle of mathematical induction"?

Comment: I would tag this as a question in logic, not number theory, since you're looking for nonstandard notions of natural numbers and the principle of induction. Usually, the principle of mathematical induction is assumed as an axiom.

Comment: Induction is part of the definition of the natural numbers, in several senses. If induction were false, whatever that means, then the natural numbers would not exist in the usual sense.

Comment: mathematical induction works by saying:

1) it's true for some value n ,
2) if true for n it can be proved true for n+1,
3) it follows that if it works for n+1 then it works for n+2 by reusing part 2,
4) it then follows that it works for all natural numbers above n.

Comment: As @QiauchuYuan says, induction is part of the definition of natural numbers, so you can't prove it. There are other equivalent ways to state is. For example, see https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/10021/why-are-induction-proofs-so-challenging-for-students/10057#10057

Comment: In the context of Set theory, it results from the axiom: $\mathbf N$ is `well-ordered` (everty non-empty subset of  $\mathbf N$ has a smallest element.

Comment: @Bernard But not as simple as replacing one for the other (to get a definition of the natural numbers). For example $\omega_0+1$ is well-ordered, has $0$ and successor but it is not the natural numbers. In particular it doesn't satisfy induction: For example "x has finitely many predecessors" satisfies the hypotheses of induction, but doesn't hold for all elements of $\omega_0+1$.

Comment: This probably depends on what logical foundation you use. In Coq one can construct the naturals and prove induction for them. IIUC proofs in Coq take the calculus of inductive constructions as their logical foundation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus_of_constructions).

Comment: I didn't say all ordinals might take the place of $\mathbf N$! Although one can proceed  by transfinite induction…

Comment: To add to @stewbasic's comment, it's worth noting that in Coq, a proof by induction is a special case of a recursive function.  The unifying principle for both of those is: if you have a dependent family of types $A_n$ for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$; you are given an element $x_0 \in A_0$; and for each $n$ you are given a function $A_n \to A_{n+1}$, then you can recursively define a function in $\prod_{n \in \mathbb{N}} A_n$ whose value at $n$ is $f_{n-1}(f_{n-2}(\cdots f_0(x_0) \cdots)) \in A_n$.

Comment: Related (to @Bernard 's comment) [Prove the principle of mathematical induction with the well ordering principle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/294178/prove-the-principle-of-mathematical-induction-with-the-well-ordering-principle?rq=1).  Also related: [Proof of the Principle of mathematical Induction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/996607/proof-of-the-principle-of-mathematical-induction?rq=1).

Comment: From what I've come across so far it really depends on context whether induction is a theorem or a principle/axiom (Note that in your question you call it a $\mathbb{principle}$). One can see this from some of the answers below. So it's important to say what context you are viewing induction in e.g. set-theoretic, type-theoretic, etc. and consider axioms closely related to it.

Comment: Does my answer address your question? If there is anything in my answer that you wish to clarify, please go ahead and comment under it, or come to [the logic chat-room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44058/logic) if you would like a longer discussion.

Answer (score 3):

It is a common misconception that induction over natural numbers can somehow be justified (in a non-circular way). This is simply impossible, and there are two parts to the reason.

---

Firstly, note that to even talk about induction we need to work within a **meta-system**. And any reasonable meta-system will already have access to the natural numbers, in the sense that it has an **inbuilt assumption** that there is a collection $N$ of objects and operations $+,\times$ on $N$ that satisfy first-order PA (or something equivalent to it). PA **already includes** the induction schema. It just makes absolutely no sense to ask for a justification of induction over natural numbers without first **defining** natural numbers, but that cannot be done without already using assumptions with PA essentially built into them.

In short, it is like asking whether there is a proof that the English language is a language. Well, in English we have already agreed upon what "the English language" refers to, which is indeed a language!

For example, ZFC set theory does not seem to have the natural numbers as basic objects, but note the axiom of infinity (Inf). It is totally meaningless unless we already believe in the existence of a **set** that is structure-isomorphic to the natural numbers, besides believing in the other ZFC axioms. Furthermore, it is nothing more than a set-theoretic version of induction! Its modern form states that "an inductive set exists":

> (Inf) $∃I ( ( ∀x ( ¬∃y ( y∈x ) ⇒ x∈I ) ∧ ∀x ( x∈I ⇒ ∀y ( ∀z ( z∈y ⇔ z∈x ∨ z=x ) ⇒ y∈I ) ) )$

The other axioms such as specification and union permit ZFC to 'implement' arithmetic operations on the set $N$ given by (Inf), as in any standard textbook, and ZFC can indeed prove that $N$ satisfies induction in terms of the conventional axiomatization of PA.

But of course you can't possibly believe that (Inf) is true unless you already believe in ZFC plus the existence of a set that is inductive (intuitively some set containing all and only the sets that can be obtained from the empty-set by a finite natural number of the successor operation $x \mapsto x \cup \{x\}$).

---

Secondly, one might still ask whether induction is superfluous, in the sense that any proof using induction can be converted to a proof without induction. No, for any reasonable interpretation of the question. Of course, one could be silly and replace induction by a slightly different axiom (or axiom schema), but as with ZFC's axiom of infinity it would be obvious to any logician that the core notion of induction cannot be justified non-circularly.

The mathematical basis is as follows. [PA$^-$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms#Equivalent_axiomatizations) is stronger than PA minus the induction schema. But PA$^-$ is strictly weaker than PA and has a model that everyone agrees is structurally different from natural numbers. Specifically, let $P$ be the collection of polynomials with integer coefficients such that the coefficient of the highest-degree term is non-negative. Then $P$ with the usual polynomial arithmetic and the ordering defined via $x<y \overset{def}\equiv x \ne y \land \exists z\ ( x+z=y )$ satisfies PA$^-$ but does not satisfy induction. This is because PA proves $Q \overset{def}\equiv \forall n\ ( \exists m\ ( n = 2m \lor n = 2m+1 ) )$ but $P$ does not satisfy $Q$, and so $P$ does not satisfy the axiom given by induction that was used in the proof of $Q$ over PA.

Comment: The question of whether or not you believe in (Inf) is a philosophical one, rather than a mathematical one. The fact is that in ZF one can prove the principle of induction, once $N$ is defined properly (at least according to all sensible definitions). Of course "believing in the principle of induction" cannot be forced unless someone already believes in it, because as you mention the very existence of $N$ relies on the axiom (Inf), which itself relies on our belief that there should be some object satisfying induction; but that doesn't mean that you can't prove induction

Comment: @Max: Yes it's philosophy whether to believe in (Inf) or not. And yes I was careful not to say that you can't prove induction in a system that already assumes induction; I specifically said "ZFC can indeed prove that $N$ satisfies induction in terms of the conventional axiomatization of PA."

Comment: Why can't you take a non-reasonable meta system?

Comment: For the meta-theory, systems significantly weaker than PA can be used such as [RCA${}_0$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_mathematics#The_big_five_subsystems_of_second_order_arithmetic). This leads to a variety of different notions of "induction over naturals" depending on what formulas we allow. I agree that you are more or less forced into believing something equivalent to a weak form of induction if you want a non-trivial meta-theory, but that's rather different than believing in the stronger form in PA, let alone second-order PA or ZFC.

Comment: You are conflating syntax with semantics in several places in your answer: you do not need semantic arguments to show that PA has a relative interpretation in ZF. (and hence show that ZF can prove every instance of the induction schema in PA). You don't need to "believe" in the semantics of these systems to do this - but you do need to believe in a metalogic that is adequate to reason about the syntax of the systems.

Comment: @galahad: The very notion of formal systems requires our assumption that finite strings and concatenation satisfy basic properties (see [this](https://www.impan.pl/~kz/files/AGKZ_Con.pdf) for details). This does not include induction, but without induction you can't prove very basic facts about strings. First you can conservatively define $unary(x) \equiv \forall p,q\ ( x=p+q \to \exists r\ ( q=α+r ) )$, where $α$ is as in the linked paper. Then with induction suitably stated you can prove that $\forall x\ ( unary(x) \to \exists y\ ( x=y+y \lor x=y+y+α ) )$. You can't do it without induction.

Comment: @DerekElkins: I am aware of RCA$_0$ and other weak subsystems of arithmetic. But I wanted to keep this post as simple as possible. Also, if you believe that PA$^-$ has a model in any usual sense, then you will be essentially forced to believe full PA, and in fact full ACA (see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1808558/21820) for details). I didn't and won't say that you ought to believe second-order arithmetic Z$_2$, not to say ZFC, since I think ACA is the furthest you can justify based on the assumed existence of the complete collection of natural numbers.

Comment: I think we are interpreting the question in different ways. I interpret the question as providing an axiomatic different to the PA (which is the one that includes the so called "induction principle") and then proving the induction principle using those axioms. I interpret that the OP does not mind the fact that the axioms may be equivalent.

Comment: @RobArthan: I do not intend to conflate syntax with semantics. But this post is partly philosophical and so do forgive the somewhat simplified presentation. As I told Max, I explicitly wrote in my answer "ZFC can indeed prove that N satisfies induction in terms of the conventional axiomatization of PA.", as you indeed pointed out in the first part of your comment. It's precisely the second part of your comment that I wished to highlight in my answer; namely that without an adequate meta-system we can't perform meaningful study of logic systems anyway.

Comment: @galahad: I do not believe that. The question in its entirety was `Is there a definition of the natural number in which someone might be able to prove "The Principle of mathematical induction"?` Taking the question your way, sure there are infinitely many trivial ways to define and construct natural numbers and prove that they satisfy induction. Choose your favourite set/type theory and go! I did sketch how ZFC can do just that. However, the bigger question about our foundational assumptions arises naturally and frequently, and hence my answer.

Comment: @galahad: But if you want an axiomatization **equivalent** to PA, one could replace the induction schema in PA by an equivalent schema with the axiom "$\exists n\ ( P(n) ) \to \exists m\ ( P(m) \land \forall n\ ( P(n) \to m \le n ) )$" for each 1-parameter arithmetical sentence $P$. Then you can work in the meta-system and show that they both give the same theory. Is that what you think was wanted?

Comment: By the way, all of you here are definitely welcome to [the logic chat-room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44058/logic) for further in-depth discussion. =)

Comment: @user21820 yes, that is exactly what I thought it was wanted.

Answer (score 2):

If your axioms include "The well ordering principle" then you can prove the principal of induction.  Here is an example of how it can be done

1. 0 is a natural number ($ 0 \in \mathbb{N}) $
2. Any successor of a natural number is a natural number ($\forall n \in \mathbb{N} . S(n) \in \mathbb{N} $)
3. 0 is equal to or less then then all natural numbers ($\forall n \in \mathbb{N} . 0 \leq n $)
4. Every natural number is less than its successor ( $\forall n \in \mathbb{N} . n < S(n)$)
5. Less then is an associative property ( $ \forall \langle a, b, c \rangle \in \mathbb{N}^3. a \leq b \land b \leq c \Rightarrow a  \leq c$)
6. Every set of natural numbers has a smallest element ($ \forall s \in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}) . \exists n \in s .\forall m \in s . n \leq m$)

From this you can derive the principle of induction via a proof by contradiction.

Assume that the principle of induction is false.  Therefor there exists a proposition $P$ for which $(P(0) \land P(n) \Rightarrow P(S(n))) \not{\Rightarrow} P(n) $. Construct a set of all numbers for which $P$ is not true $ N = \{ n \in \mathbb{N} : \lnot P(n) \} $.  By the principal of well ordering there must be a minimal element m in $N$. By the definitional of a natural number m must either be 0 or a successor of another natural number.

The minimal element m can't be 0 as $P(0)$ is true.  However if m is not zero then it must be a successor of some other natural number n. If $P(n)$ is true then $P(n) \Rightarrow P(S(n))$ is contradicted but if $P(n)$ is false then m isn't the minimal member of $N$.

All possibilities lead to a contradiction therefore our initial assumption must have been false and the principal of induction holds.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are a few.

In a type-theoretic setting, you can define the naturals as an inductive type and then prove induction by structural recursion. Here's how you could do it in Coq:

```
Inductive natural : Set :=
| zero : natural
| succ : natural -> natural.

Definition natural_induction :
  forall P, P zero ->
    (forall n, P n -> P (succ n)) ->
    forall n, P n :=
fun P Pzero Psucc => fix rec n :=
match n return P n with
| zero => Pzero
| succ n' => Psucc n' (rec n')
end.
```

In a set-theoretic setting, one common way of defining the naturals is as the finite von Neumann ordinals—that is, $0 = \emptyset, 1 = \{0\}, 2 = \{0, 1\}, 3 = \{0, 1, 2\}...$ Let's say that a set $S$ is *inductive* if $\emptyset \in S$, and for any $x \in S$ we have $x \cup \{x\} \in S$ (that is, the successor of $x$ is in $S$). Then in ZFC, the axiom of infinity tells us that there is at least one inductive set—let's call it $I$. We can define the naturals $\mathbb N$ as the intersection of every inductive subset of $I$. From this, the principle of induction follows almost immediately: Given an inductive subset $S$ of $\mathbb N$, we have $S \subseteq \mathbb N \subseteq I$, and any inductive subset of $I$ contains $\mathbb N$, since $\mathbb N$ is defined as the intersection of all of them. Then we have $S \subseteq \mathbb N$ and $\mathbb N \subseteq S$, so $S = \mathbb N$.

Comment: So this is basically a proof of one type of induction from another type of induction?

Comment: However structural recursion is induction in another form.

Comment: It has a clear computational interpretation, though!

Comment: @benzrf This is even more tautological than DanielV's comment suggests. The `Inductive` declaration, behind the scenes, [automatically asserts `natural_induction`](https://coq.inria.fr/tutorial/2-induction#htoc23) (as `natural_rec`) and that is what is used to handle the pattern matching in your definition. So, you aren't even proving induction in terms of another type of induction, you are proving a type of induction in terms of itself.

Comment: No, that's not true. "natural_rec" isn't "asserted", it has code generated for it which is basically similar to what I've pasted here. Pattern matching and recursion are primitive.

Comment: You are correct that Coq doesn't directly use `natural_rec`. As [described in the Coq reference manual](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/refman/Reference-Manual006.html#sec196), it factors the primitive recursion such an eliminator represents into `fix` and `match`. However, `fix` and `match` can't be used without an inductive definition in scope. An inductive type isn't *reduced* to a more general notion of induction (e.g. over W-types); its declaration *extends* `fix` and `match` in a way that is logically (but not computationally or ergonomically) equivalent to asserting the eliminator.

Answer (score -1):

A working list of the [Peano Axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms) defining the natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$ is:

1. In the set of the natural numbers there is an element named `1`.
2. For every natural $n$ there is another natural, named **successor**, denoted by $n+1$.
3. There are no natural numbers $n$ for which $n+1 = n$.
4. If $n+1 = m+1$ for two natural numbers $n$ and $m$, then $n=m$.
5. If $S$ is a subset of the naturals satisfying that $1\in S$ and if $k\in S$ then $k+1\in S$, then $S = \mathbb{N}$.

Since these are *axioms*, there is nothing to prove. Notice how the last axiom can be rewritten as:

- If there is a function $P:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \{T,F\}$ satisfying that $P(1) = T$ and that if $P(k) = T$ then $P(k+1) = T$, then $P(n) = T$ for every natural $n$.

Which is precisely the Induction Principle.

Consider now the natural numbers defined as [ordinals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number) (notice that with these axioms we require the empty set to exist): define $1 = \{\emptyset \}$ and $n+1 = n \cup \{n\}$, and by definition $\mathbb{N} = \{1,2,3,\dots\}$ (one can include $0 = \emptyset$ if it so desires). Notice that under the definition as ordinals, $\mathbb{N}$ is a well-ordered set with respect to the inclusion, namely $n\subset n+1$.

We prove the fifth Peano axiom: suppose we have $S$ a subset of the naturals satisfying that $1\in S$ and if $k\in S$ then $k+1\in S$. If $S = \mathbb{N}$, we are done. Suppose $S \neq \mathbb{N}$, then the set $T = \{n\in\mathbb{N} : n\notin S\}$ is a non-empty subset of a well-ordered set $\mathbb{N}$, meaning that it has a least element, say $m$. Since $1\in S$ we have $m \neq 1$ so $\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\in m$. By construction $m$ is a well-ordered set and contains only a finite number of sets, thus it contains a maximal set $k$. Again by construction, we have that $m = k\cup \{k\}$ so $m = k+1$. Since having $k\in T$ contradicts that $m$ is the least element in $T$, we have that $k\in S$ and thus by hypothesis $m = k+1\in S$, a contradiction.

Comment: but he asked for a definition where it wouldn't be an axiom.

Comment: I think this edit answers the question.

Comment: By the way, I wish to point out a serious flaw in your answer. You have conflated first-order and second-order PA. They are totally different. It is **not true** that the fifth Peano axiom is equivalent to what you claim is a rewriting. The five Peano axioms are in fact insufficient to actually do anything much because it doesn't include any set-existence axioms, and so the fifth axiom becomes useless. In contrast, in modern logic PA refers to first-order PA, which requires the induction schema, which has one axiom for each 1-parameter arithmetical sentence.

Comment: Maybe I'm using the word `predicate` when I shouldn't, let me rewrite that. The existence of the natural numbers is guaranteed by the first axiom.

Comment: I think what's happening is that you're too used to working within a set theory, because what you're claiming is only true in specific kinds of set theories such as ZFC. As I said earlier, the five Peano's axioms aren't sufficient for axiomatizing the natural numbers, so you'd have to add set-existence axioms otherwise they fail to define the natural numbers. Feel free to ask further if you don't understand this.